Counting the number of local minima of a function that is the sum of square roots of cosines
Suppose you are given a set of functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n$. Every function is defined as follows
$$f_i(x) = \sqrt{1+C^2_i-2C_i\cos (x-D_i)}$$
where $0<C_i<1$ and $0\leq D_i<2\pi$ are real-valued constants and $x\in \mathbb R$. Now we restrict $x$ to an interval $]a,b[$, s.t.,
\begin{align}
\forall i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i(x)<f_j(x) &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i(x)>f_j(x) \\
\forall i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i'(x)<f_j'(x) &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i'(x)>f_j'(x) \\
\forall i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i''(x)<f_j''(x) &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i''(x)>f_j''(x) \\
\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i(x)<0 &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i(x)>0 \\
\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i'(x)<0 &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i'(x)>0 \\
\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} ~~\forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i''(x)<0 &~~\lor \forall x\!\in]a, b[:& ~~f_i''(x)>0
\end{align}
In words within the interval $]a,b[$ the following holds:

there is a strict total order over all functions
there is a strict total order of their first derivative (although it does not need to be the same order)
there is a strict total order of their second derivative (although it does not need to be the same order)
no function intersects the $x$-axis
no function has an extremum
no function has an inflection point

Question: How many minima can the function $f_{\Sigma}(x) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x)$ have within the interval $]a,b[$?
My hope is that the answer to the question is that there can only be one or a constant number of minima, but I would also be happy with any polynomial upper OR exponential lower bound.
What I've tried:
Initially I hoped that the minimum of the sum function would necessarily coincide with a point of the summands, of which there are only $O(n)$, like extrema and inversion points. This does not seems to be true. Then I tried: "Between any two minima of the sum, there has to be a minimum/maximum/inversion point of a summand function", but no such statement seems to be true either. I am not entirely convinced that a charging argument will not work, but I have not been able to find the right angle.
Next I have tried to accumulate the functions into a constant number of functions by grouping them into four sets $F^+_+, F^+_-, F^-_+$ and $F^-_-$, s.t., any function in the set $F^+_-$ has positive first derivative and negative second derivative (and similar for the other three sets). Summing up all of the functions in these sets yields four functions $$
f^+_+(x) =\!\! \sum\limits_{f\in F^+_+} f(x),~~~
f^+_-(x) =\!\! \sum\limits_{f\in F^+_-} f(x),~~~
f^-_+(x) =\!\! \sum\limits_{f\in F^-_+} f(x),~~~
f^-_-(x) =\!\! \sum\limits_{f\in F^-_-} f(x)
$$
and we can observe that we retain that for, e.g., $f^+_-$ the first derivative is entirely positive and the second is entirely negative within $]a,b[$ (and similar for $f^+_+, f^-_-, f^-_+$). Note that these function do not necessarily have a total order anymore, nor do their derivatives. The hope was that reducing the number of functions to just 4 would be helpful, but I could not figure out how to proceed from here.
I have also tried to plot these functions in Mathematica and I have not encountered any instance with more than $n$ minima, which is where my suspicion comes from that the answer is $O(n)$.
Alternative follow up question: If it is for some reason not possible to give any upper bound on the number of minima, what would be a sufficient property of these functions to obtain one?
This question has now also been asked on Mathoverflow.

It seems this question isn't asked correctly, seeing that it has gathered no interaction whatsoever. I would actually be happy to know why that is (question is trivial, question doesn't make sense, question is too wordy/not detailed enough, simply asked at an inopportune time, there's no interest in this question on this webpage, ...)

You have included a lot of precise details and explained your own workings, both of which make this question stand out to me as interesting and worth engaging with.
I suspect the reason you have not gathered interaction is that, at least to me, it is not clear why this question is interesting. I would suggest explaining where this question comes from, and why you suspect the answer could be of the forms you desire.

It seems likely that this question falls into that awkward gap between those questions that are simple enough that many users could answer them and those difficult questions which are of interest to experts.

@Numeral I suspect the reason you have not gathered interaction is that, at least to me, it is not clear why this question is interesting Not really. It is just surprisingly hard, if you start thinking of it in serious; one of those riddles where the setup is crystal clear, but the right approach is extremely elusive. I don't have a solution myself yet. A few ideas I tried on it all failed, though a couple of times I thought I was close...

The equation for $f$ is important here. Otherwise, we could come up with the counter-example of ${e^x,-e^x}$ which meets the given criteria but is constant $100$ on any interval.

@Numeral Here's a geometric interpretation that might make it more interesting: Consider $n$ points in the unit disk. Let $f_{\Sigma}:S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ be the sum of distances from a point on the unit circle to each of the given points. Can we bound the number of minimum of $f_{\Sigma}$, if we are just considering an open interval of the  unit circle where the conditions are met? I'm not sure what a nice geometric interpretation of those conditions is, but this is basically the asked question.

And I think more generally, even if those conditions don't hold, but we still have the same geometric interpretation, it's still bounded by $n+2$.

@Numeral The interpretation of Varun is very nice. In fact this comes from a geometric setting with points in a (unit) disk, which is very close to this. A point in a disk is connected to a point on the boundary with a straight line. Then you rotate the point on the boundary once around disk. One of these functions describes the length of the line during the rotation. If you have $n$ such point pairs and they all rotate at the same speed, then the sum describes the total length.

Since these functions have one minimum, one maximum and two inflection points, we can split these functions into $O(n)$ "horizontal strips" where their derivatives behave nicely.

Just a piece of advise: some months ago, I had bountied a StackOverflow question (also 500 points) and before I even realised, two people had immediately written an answer. At first I was surprised by their swift action, but I quickly realised that they had simply copied my question on ChatGPT and copied/pasted the A.I. response. I'm just saying: be very careful with such high bounties. Good luck.

Right, the question is crying for the geometrical interpretation. I also tried it, but I stuck, so I wrote my analytical answer
instead, which is a bit more advanced. I stuck with the geometric interpretation even in the case $n=2$, which looks especially nice. Indeed, let $O$ be the center of the disk and $P_1$ and $P_2$ be the given point.

Then for any fixed $d>|P_1P_2|$ the set of points $P$ of the plane such that $|PP_1|+|PP_2|=d$ is an ellipse with the foci $P_1$ and $P_2$. Then it seems that a point $P$ of the circle is extremal iff the ellipse with the foci $P_1$ and $P_2$ passing through $P$ is tangent to the circle at $P$, that is the segments $OP_1$ and $OP_2$ are seen from $P$ at the same angles. Unfortunately, I failed to find the geometric place of points of the plane with satisfying the latter property.

@VarunVejalla I guess in your counterexample with ${e^x,-e^x}$ the constant should be $0$ instead of $100$. Also, I do not see how we obtain the bound $n+2$ from your geometric interpretation.

@Dominique That is a valid point. I have also tried using generative AI out of curiosity before I posted the question here, but even with various different formulations of the question, the answers were simply wrong. ChatGPT basically claimed that the sum of $n$ functions with $O(1)$ minima can only ever have $O(n)$ minima.

@AlexRavsky I have no idea why I wrote $100$ instead of $0$ haha. And I didn't mean to imply $n+2$ follows easily from the geometric interpretation - I just meant that I think there's at most $n+2$ local minima even if the six conditions in the question don't hold.

@Dominique Thanks for your care. But I am tracking bounty questions at Mathematics.SE for years and I recognized no instance when an AI generated answer was awarded. I think their usual fate here is to be downvoted and deleted.

@Dominique Oh, I suspect that you were right and the new answer by a person with $1$ reputation was AI generated.

Since the function $\cos x$ (and so $f_\Sigma(x)$) has a period $2\pi$, it suffices to study the local minima of the function $f_\Sigma(x)$ on any interval $I$ of length $2\pi$. In this answer we study the upper bound of the number of all minima of the function $f_\Sigma(x)$ on the interval $I$.
Suppose that $x\not\in \frac{\pi}2+\pi\mathbb Z$. Put $t=\tan \frac x2$. Then $\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, $\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, and so for each natural $i\le n$ we have
$$1+C^2_i-2C_i\cos (x-D_i)=$$ $$1+C^2_i-2C_i(\cos x\cos D_i+\sin x\sin D_i)=$$ $$\frac {a_i t^2+b_it+c_i}{t^2+1},$$
where $a_i=1+C_i^2+2C_i\cos D_i$, $b_i=-4C_i\sin D_i$, and $c_i=1+C_i^2-2C_i\cos D_i$. Note that the polynomial $a_i t^2+b_it+c_i$ has no real roots, because its discriminant
$$b_i^2-4a_ic_i=$$ $$16 C_i^2\sin^2 D_i-4(1+C_i^2+2C_i\cos D_i)(1+C_i^2-2C_i\cos D_i)=$$
$$16 C_i^2\sin^2 D_i-4((1+C_i^2)^2-(2C_i\cos D_i)^2)=$$ $$-4\cdot (1+C_i^2)^2+16C_i^2=-4-8C_i^2+4C_i^4+16C_i^2=$$ $$-4+8C_i^2+4C_i^4=-4(1-C_i^2)<0.$$
We have $f_\Sigma(x)=g_\Sigma(t)$, where
$$g_\Sigma(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\frac {a_i t^2+b_i+c_i}{t^2+1}}.$$
If $f_\Sigma(x)$ attains the local minimum at $x$ then $g_\Sigma(t)$ attains a local minimum at $t$, so
$$0=g'_\Sigma(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 12\sqrt{\frac {t^2+1}{a_i t^2+b_i t+c_i}}\cdot \frac{(2a_it+b_i)(t^2+1)-(a_i t^2+b_i+c_i)\cdot 2t}{(t^2+1)^2}.$$
Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_it^2+2(c_i-a_i)t-b_i}{\sqrt{a_i t^2+b_i+c_i}}=0.\tag{1}$$
When $n=2$ then it implies the equation
$$(a_1t^2+b_1t+c_1)(b_2t^2+2(c_2-a_2)t-b_2)^2=(a_2t^2+b_2t+c_2)(b_1t^2+2(c_1-a_1)t-b_1)^2$$
of the sixth degree. It has at most six roots, but the case when it is an identity.
Let us consider the latter case. For each natural $i\le 2$ the polynomial $b_it^2+2(c_i-a_i)t-b_i$ has two real roots, because its discriminant $4(c_i-a_i)^2+4b_i^2\ge 0$. Since the polynomial $a_i t^2+b_it+c_i$ has no real roots, we see that
$$t^2+\frac {b_1}{a_1}t+\frac {c_1}{a_1}\equiv t^2+\frac {b_2}{a_2}t+\frac {c_2}{a_2},$$
and so
$$\frac{(b_1t^2+2(c_1-a_1)t-b_1)^2}{a_1}\equiv \frac{(b_2t^2+2(c_2-a_2)t-b_2)^2}{a_2}\equiv$$
$$\frac{\left(\frac {b_1}{a_1}\cdot a_2t^2+2\left(\frac {c_1}{a_1}\cdot a_2- \frac {a_1}{a_1}\cdot a_2\right)t-\frac {b_1}{a_1}\cdot a_2\right)^2}{a_2}\equiv $$ $$\left(\frac {a_2}{a_1}\right)^2\cdot  \frac{(b_1t^2+2(c_1-a_1)t-b_1)^2}{a_2}.$$
Therefore $a_1=a_2$. But then $b_1t^2+2(c_1-a_1)t-b_1=0$ by (1), so there are at most two roots $t$.
When $n>2$ then I expect we still can derive from (1) a polynomial equation if we replace the left-hand side of (1) by the product of all $2^{n-1}$ sums of the form $g_1(t)\pm g_2(t)\dots \pm g_n(t)$, where for each natural $i\le n$ we have
$$g_i(t)=\frac{b_it^2+2(c_i-a_i)t-b_i}{\sqrt{a_i t^2+b_i+c_i}}.$$
Unfortunately, I expect that the degree of the obtained equation grows exponentially with respect to $n$.
Finally, I remark that I expect in our study of the number of minima we can get rid of the restriction $x\not\in \frac{\pi}2+\pi\mathbb Z$, by shifting all $D_i$ by the same value to ensure that the function $f_\Sigma(x)$ attains no local extremum at these $x$. Moreover, I expect that when we increase the angle $x$ then local minima of $f_\Sigma(x)$ are interleaved by its local maxima. In particular, since $f_\Sigma(x)$ is periodic, I expect that for $n=2$, $f_\Sigma(x)$ has at most three local minima in $[0,2 \pi)$.

Consider the number of minima for the function $f_{\Sigma}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$ on the interval $]a, b[$, given a family of functions $f_i(x)$ that obey strict ordering properties with respect to derivatives and signs, as well as smoothness conditions — specifically, there are no extrema or inflection points inside $]a, b[$.
To analyze this, let’s break down the properties and examine the behavior of $ f_\Sigma(x)$ accordingly.
Key Observations and Constraints

Strict Total Order on Each $f_i(x)$ and Their Derivatives:

For each function $f_i(x)$, we have $f_i(x) \lt f_j(x), f'_i(x) \lt f'_j(x)$, and $f''_i(x) < f''_j(x)$ (or the opposite for all derivatives).
This ordering implies that each $f_i(x)$ is monotonic due to the absence of extrema or points of inflection within $]a, b[$, and it imposes a strict ordering on their rates of change.


Sign Constraints:

All functions are either negative — that is, $f_i(x) < 0$, $f'_i(x) < 0, f''_i(x) < 0$ for all $x \in ]a, b[$ — or all are positive, meaning $f_i(x) > 0, f'_i(x) > 0, f''_i(x) > 0$ for all $x \in ]a, b[$.
This enforces that each ( f_i(x) ) is strictly either increasing or decreasing throughout the interval $]a, b[$.


Behavior of the Sum Function $f_\Sigma(x)$:

Since each $f_i(x)$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, the overall behavior of $f_\Sigma(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$ depends on the collective trend.
If all $f_i(x)$ are strictly increasing, then $f_\Sigma(x)$ will also be strictly increasing, implying no minima in the interval $]a, b[$.
Similarly, if all $f_i(x)$ are strictly decreasing, $f_\Sigma(x)$ will be strictly decreasing, again meaning no minima.


Mixed Behavior:

In the case where some functions are increasing and others are decreasing, this mixed behavior could lead to “turning points” in $f_\Sigma(x)$, where local minima may occur.



Can Multiple Minima Occur?
Since each $f_i(x)$ has no extrema or points of inflection within $]a, b[$, any local minimum in $f_\Sigma(x)$ must be due to an interaction between the increasing and decreasing functions. Given the ordered structure on the derivatives, this means:

The combination of a structured, bounded set of monotonic functions, either entirely decreasing or increasing, and the ordering constraints on the derivatives implies that $f_\Sigma(x)$ cannot oscillate unpredictably. The monotonic behavior of each $f_i(x)$ bounds the overall behavior of the sum, likely resulting in at most one minimum or a few, especially around transitions between groups of functions with differing monotonic trends.

Thus, while we cannot rule out multiple minima in general for mixed monotonicity, it is reasonable to expect that $f_\Sigma(x)$ can have at most $O(n)$ minima. This upper bound could occur when there are numerous transitions from increasing to decreasing (and vice versa) among the functions in the sum, with each transition potentially introducing at most one additional turning point. This gives a possible upper bound proportional to $n$.
Further Elaboration

Upper Bound on the Number of Minima:

The analysis aligns with the hypothesis that $O(n)$ is an upper bound on the number of minima for $f_\Sigma(x)$.


Conditions for a Tighter Bound:

If there are additional constraints, such as limits on the number of functions with varying monotonic behavior, the number of minima could be reduced further.
A sufficient condition to ensure only one minimum could be that $f_\Sigma(x)$ itself is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, or that the functions are combined in such a way that positive and negative contributions due to increasing and decreasing trends cancel out potential turning points.



In summary, given the structure and monotonic behavior of each $f_i(x)$, the number of minima for $f_\Sigma(x)$ within the interval $]a, b[$ is at most $O(n)$.

Can you elaborate how the structure and monotonic behavior of each $f_i(x)$ imply the bold conclusion that the number of minima for $f_\Sigma(x)$ within the interval $]a, b[$ is at most $O(n)$?
